# Springboot application fails to find bootstrap and jquery added by webjars

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, webjars

Here are my dependencies in pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>    
    <!-- thymeleaf -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-java8time</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
        <version>0.32</version>
    </dependency>    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.7-1</version>
    </dependency>    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap-datepicker</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

this is my configuration file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("/webjars/");
    }
}
```

and this is how I added bootstrap and jquery to my html template:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Default Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css}" />
    <script th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/styles.css}" />
</head>
```

The bootstrap styles are not applied and when I open the developer console I see there are 404 errors saying css and js files could not be found. Well this seems to be a very common problem for beginners, However I read some questions here regarding this problem. like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32685819/spring-boot-webjars-unable-to-load-javascript-library-through-webjar/32710851)
 but did not solve my problem. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

With Spring Boot, WebJars are auto-configured. There is no need to add any handlers or other configurations. When you run your application, you can see a log like this:

```
... Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
```

It seems weird but deleting your configuration file probably resolves the problem. In fact my Spring Boot application was exactly the same as yours (but without that configuration file) and worked perfectly. When I added your configuration to my application, WebJars didn't work anymore!